# Why is Sakusa considered one of the top 3 aces in the country?

Tags: haikyuu

It is shown in *Haikyuu* that Sakusa from itachiyama High is one of the top three spikers/aces in the country. But from the knowledge that I have from manga and anime there is no such information.

If I remember, most information about Sakusa is given in the last arc. In Chapter 394 it is shown that he is great at receiving, and it's also shown that his arm is flexible. But compare that to Bokuto who has an amazing cross-shot and is great at line show.

Whereas if we look at Sakusa, even at the national youth camp he was a totally average player.

Am I missing something? Or is there nothing good about Sakusa except his flexible arm and that alone makes him superior to every player in the country?

I know that it is also shown that he works very hard, but so does everyone else, so that doesn't count in his favor.

Comment: "Top three spikers in the country" does not mean "top three players in the country". It means "top three spikers in the country". Spiking is only one aspect of volleyball.

Comment: yeah but if we look at wakatoshi or kiryu they have much more than thier arm that made the top three spikers. Whereas in case of sakusa only his flexible arm won't make him superior than bokuto. 
And also his speciality is also shown as receiving instead of spiking `chapter-394`.
What do you think about this?

Comment: To complicate the matter, is Sakusa considered as one of the top 3 [*aces*](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/32090/2516), or *spikers*?

Comment: @AkiTanaka
Both ace and spiker [here](https://haikyuu.fandom.com/wiki/Kiyoomi_Sakusa) `He is the only second-year among the top three spikers in the country` <- Read this in trivia 
`Kiyoomi Sakusa (Japanese: 佐久早さくさ 聖臣きよおみ Sakusa Kiyoomi) was the ace spiker for Itachiyama Institute, a heavy favorite to win the nationals` <-this in the introduction.